# Explanation of Data Structure Implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I came across this piece of code for a computer science question, and they asked me to identify the type of data structure it implemented:

```
public class Demo
{
        boolean state;
    private Disc east, west;
    private int i;
    static int n
    public Disc() {i = ++n;)
    public Disc(Disc w, Disc e){
    }
        this();
        bind(w,this);
        bind(this,e);
    }
    public static void bind(Disc w, Disc e){
        w.east = e;
        e.east = w;
    }
    public boolean flip(){
        if(state && east != null)
            east.state  = !east.state;
            if(!state && west != null)
                west.state = !west.state();
            return state = !state;
    }
    public Disc get(int x){
        Disc d = this;
        while(d.east != null) d = d.east;
        do{ d = d.west}
        while(d != null && d.i != x);
        return d;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String s= "";
        Disc d = this;
        while(d.east != null) d = d.east;
        do{
            s+= d.i + (d.state? "H ": "T ");
            d = d.west;
        } while(d != null);
        return s;
    }
}
```

I believe this is Doubly LinkedList because of the two directions pointing towards other `Discs` (If anyone can link me to a previous post that discusses Doubly LinkedLists or a different explanation, that would be much appreciated).

What boggle me was the second question which presented a main method that asked me to find output.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Disc base = new Disc();
    Disc disc = new Disc();
    Disc.bind(base, disc);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        disc = new Disc(base, disc);
    out.println(base); //<#1>
    Disc dFour = base.get(4);
    Disc.bind(base.get(6), disc.get(3));
    out.println(base); //<#2>
    base.get(3).flip();
    out.println(disc); //<#3>
    out.println(dFour); //<#4>
}
```

The first three lines make sense because `base` and `disc` are bound together. The for loop reassigns the address of `disc` to a new object that is a link between `base` and the original disc `disc`. Unfortunately, the idea of aliasing makes this implementation a whole lot harder for me to understand.

Comment: That code won't compile

Comment: @Angel - is this right? 
        w.east = e;
        e.east = w;
    -- i would expect it to be e.west = w;

Comment: Sorry for replying late. It is `e.west=w`